# which method can i call in VideoView object like setImageResource

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-videoview

I want to write following code for VideoView.Because i want to show 4 video file in screen with Gridview Layout.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by using **setVideoPath(String path)**.))

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageDrawable(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
 }
```

Comment: i think you didnt understand my question.I want to show video files in screen with griview Layout

Comment: Hmm Sorry for ans.. Did you using gridview in your xml ??

Comment: Yes. i use gridview.xml file

Comment: Good if you don mind can you share the gridview code

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >

</GridView>

Comment: instead of numColumns="auto_fit" you can give there  numColumns="4"